# pandas join with condition using LIKE operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, sql-like

I have 2 dataframes:
**users**

```
 user_id    position
0   201 Senior Engineer
1   207 Senior System Architect
2   223 Senior account manage
3   212 Junior Manager
4   112 junior Engineer
5   311 junior python developer
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['201', '207', '223', '212', '112', '311'],
                   'position': ['Senior Engineer', 'Senior System Architect', 'Senior account manage', 'Junior Manager', 'junior Engineer', 'junior python developer']})
```

**roles**

```
 role_id     role_position
0   10         %senior%
1   20         %junior%
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'role_id': ['10', '20'],
                   'role_position': ['%senior%', '%junior%']})
```

I want to join them to get role_id for each row in df1 using condition something like this:

```
lower(df1.position) LIKE df2.role_position
```

I want to use operator LIKE (like in SQL).
So it would look like this (or without role_position - it would be even better):

```
user_id position                role_id  role_position
0   201 Senior Engineer           10      %senior%
1   207 Senior System Architect   10      %senior%
2   223 Senior account manage     10      %senior%
3   212 Junior Manager            20      %junior%
4   112 junior Engineer           20      %junior%
5   311 junior python developer   20      %junior%
```

How can i make this?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider accepting one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract()`+`merge()`:

```
pat='('+'|'.join(df2['role_position'].str.strip('%').unique())+')'
df1['role_position']='%'+df1['position'].str.lower().str.extract(pat,expand=False)+'%'
df1=df1.merge(df2,on='role_position',how='left')
```

output of `df1`:

```
user_id position                role_id  role_position
0   201 Senior Engineer           10      %senior%
1   207 Senior System Architect   10      %senior%
2   223 Senior account manage     10      %senior%
3   212 Junior Manager            20      %junior%
4   112 junior Engineer           20      %junior%
5   311 junior python developer   20      %junior%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save some trouble by doing a `merge` directly if the seniority level always start at front:

```
print (pd.merge(df, df2,
                left_on=df["position"].str.split().str[0].str.lower(),
                right_on=df2["role_position"].str.strip("%")).drop("key_0", axis=1))
```

Else you can do a `pd.Series.str.extract` during a `merge`:

```
pat = f'({"|".join(df2["role_position"].str.strip("%"))})'

print (pd.merge(df, df2,
                left_on=df["position"].str.extract(pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).str.lower(),
                right_on=df2["role_position"].str.strip("%")).drop("key_0", axis=1))
```

Both yields the same result:

```
  user_id                 position role_id role_position
0     201          Senior Engineer      10      %senior%
1     207  Senior System Architect      10      %senior%
2     223    Senior account manage      10      %senior%
3     212           Junior Manager      20      %junior%
4     112          junior Engineer      20      %junior%
5     311  junior python developer      20      %junior%
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

- [fuzzy words](https://www.google.com/search?q=fuzzy%20in%20pandas&rlz=1C5CHFA_enPL889PL889&oq=fuzzy%20in%20pandas&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i10i22i30j0i22i30.2529j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- [Sequence Matcher](https://towardsdatascience.com/sequencematcher-in-python-6b1e6f3915fc)
- [.extract](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-extract/#:%7E:text=extract()%20function%20is%20used,match%20of%20regular%20expression%20pat.)

---

```
    df1['Similarity'] = 0
        df1['Role'] = 0
        
        from difflib import SequenceMatcher
        def similar(a, b):
            return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
        
        for index, row in df1.iterrows(): 
            for x in df2['role_position']:
                z = similar(row['position'],x)
                if z >= 0.20: 
                    df1.loc[index, "Similarity"] = z
                    df1.loc[index, "Role"] = x
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a dict of mappings and then map the values:

```
df2['role_position'] = df2['role_position'].str.strip('%')
mappings = df2.set_index('role_position').to_dict('dict')['role_id']

>> mappings
{'senior': '10', 'junior': '20'}
```

Using a regular expression we can extract the roles for each position:

```
re_roles = f"({df2['role_position'].str.cat(sep='|')})"

position = df1['position'].str.extract(re_roles, flags=re.I).iloc[:, 0].str.lower()
>> position 

0    senior
1    senior
2    senior
3    junior
4    junior
5    junior
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

And finally map the `role_id` using the mappings dictionary:

```
df1['role_id'] = position.map(mappings)

>> df1 

  user_id                 position role_id
0     201          Senior Engineer      10
1     207  Senior System Architect      10
2     223    Senior account manage      10
3     212           Junior Manager      20
4     112          junior Engineer      20
5     311  junior python developer      20
```